# Lenovo OneCLI - wrapping powershell around it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a wrapper around Lenovo's onecli.exe (https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/hr/en/downloads/ds552146) to allow me run commands using PowerShell. The syntax is this, and it works in a `cmd.exe` window:

```sh
F:\>f:\temp\onecli\onecli.exe config show SYSTEM_PROD_DATA --bmc USERID:ChangeME@192.168.1.100

Lenovo XClarity Essentials OneCLI lxce_onecli01q-3.3.0 (C) Lenovo 2013-2021 All Rights Reserved OneCLI License Agreement and OneCLI Legal Information can be found at the following location: "f:\temp\onecli\Lic" [1s]Certificate check finished [100%][=========================================================================================================>]

Start to connect BMC at 192.168.1.100 to apply config show
Invoking SHOW command ... Connected to BMC at IP address 192.168.1.100 by IPMI
SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoProdName=SomeProductName SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoProdIdentifier=SomeLenovoServer
SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoSerialNum=J1234567 SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysInfoUUID=BE8E461E735611EBA50B7ED30A546A93
SYSTEM_PROD_DATA.SysEncloseAssetTag= Succeed.
```

If I run the same syntax in PowerShell window, it somehow stops parsing the command at the "-b" point. How can I make it so that I get the same behaviour on PS as I do in cmd?

I tried various options with parameters in single/double quotes, almost all items on this list, and they don't work:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

```sh
PS C:\> f:\temp\onecli\onecli.exe config show SYSTEM_PROD_DATA --bmc USERID:ChangeMe@192.168.1.100

Lenovo XClarity Essentials OneCLI lxce_onecli01q-3.3.0
(C) Lenovo 2013-2021 All Rights Reserved

OneCLI License Agreement and OneCLI Legal Information can be found at the following location:
    "F:\temp\onecli\Lic"

Start to connect current machine's BMC inband to apply config show
Failed to connect KCS, please check IPMI over KCS status.
```

Edit: The error with connectivity is not related to the system being unresponsive at the other end, it is because parsing stops at config show .... which means onecli will not try a remote XCC address, instead it will try to connect inband, and that fails, since i'm running the code from a VM,

Also, I noticed something "strange".
So if I just copy paste the code from CMD - the top level error happens.
however if I remove the --bmc and then type it back, it changes color in the PS commandline, like below - and goes through successfully.
[image: PS behaving strange when asked to run the same command]

Is PS doing some sort of parameter discovery, or what's the deal with syntax highlighting here?

Btw running PS 5.1, but i don't think that matters.

thank for your help.
ionut

Comment: If you don't need any powershell functionality (like subexpressions or variables), you can use the "stop parser operator" `--%` which will use the cmd parser for the rest of the line.

Comment: While there are differences between how `cmd.exe` and PowerShell parse command lines, they don't apply to your particular command line; it sounds like the failure you've experienced was incidental (temporary unavailability of the target server).

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - I actually need subexpression and variables, and I tried the stop parser option, and it does not seem to work.


mklement0 - I've updated my original question, I thought so too, as it turns out, it is just trying to connect locally not remotely to XCC, because somehow he stops parsing before --bmc parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue, the problem was a non UTF-8 character in the string I was pasting into powershell, the 1st "-" from --bmc was a UTF-8 BOM character and that was causing onecli to stop parsing the output after that.

I "dumbed" it down to ANSI and it showed something else than a "-",

```html
â€“-bmc
```

Thanks everyone for the help.